# Why can't an object use a method as an attribute in the Python package ComplexNetworkSim?

Tags: python-2.7, agent-based-modeling

I'm trying to use the Python package [ComplexNetworkSim](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ComplexNetworkSim), which inherits from [networkx](http://networkx.lanl.gov/) and [SimPy](http://simpy.sourceforge.net/), to simulate an [agent-based model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent-based_model) of how messages propagate within networks.

Here is my code:

```
from ComplexNetworkSim import NetworkSimulation, NetworkAgent, Sim
import networkx as nx

#define constants for our example of states
NO_MESSAGE = 0 
MESSAGE = 1

class Message(object):
    def __init__(self,topic_pref):
        self.relevance = topic_pref

class myAgent(NetworkAgent):
    def __init__(self, state, initialiser):
        NetworkAgent.__init__(self, state, initialiser)
        self.state = MESSAGE
        self.topic_pref = 0.5

    def Run(self):
        while True:
            if self.state == MESSAGE:
                self.message = self.Message(topic_pref, self, TIMESTEP)
                yield Sim.hold, self, NetworkAgent.TIMESTEP_DEFAULT
            elif self.state == NO_MESSAGE:
                yield Sim.hold, self, NetworkAgent.TIMESTEP_DEFAULT

# Network and initial states of agents
nodes = 30 

G = nx.scale_free_graph(nodes)
states = [MESSAGE for n in G.nodes()]  

# Simulation constants
MAX_SIMULATION_TIME = 25.0
TRIALS = 2

def main():
    directory = 'test' #output directory

    # run simulation with parameters
    # - complex network structure
    # - initial state list
    # - agent behaviour class
    # - output directory
    # - maximum simulation time
    # - number of trials
    simulation = NetworkSimulation(G,
                                   states,
                                   myAgent,
                                   directory,
                                   MAX_SIMULATION_TIME,
                                   TRIALS)
    simulation.runSimulation()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

(There may be other problems downstream with this code and it is not fully tested.)

My problem is that **the myAgent object is not properly calling the method Run as an attribute**. Specifically, this is the error message that I get when I try to run the above code:

```
Starting simulations...
---Trial 0 ---
set up agents...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "simmessage.py", line 55, in <module>
    main()
  File "simmessage.py", line 52, in main
    simulation.runSimulation()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ComplexNetworkSim-0.1.2-py2.7.egg/ComplexNetworkSim/simulation.py", line 71, in runSimulation
    self.runTrial(i)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ComplexNetworkSim-0.1.2-py2.7.egg/ComplexNetworkSim/simulation.py", line 88, in runTrial
    self.activate(agent, agent.Run())            
AttributeError: 'myAgent' object has no attribute 'Run'
```

Does anybody know why this is? I can't figure how my code differs substantially from the example in [ComplexNetworkSim](http://packages.python.org/ComplexNetworkSim/start.html).

Comment: Perhaps semantics, I think you mean *accessing* the method Run. What does your `main()` function look like?

Comment: Main just runs the simulation -- it's in the code.

Comment: just a guess: some combination of mixed tabs and spaces in indentation may be indiscernible (in a weak text editor), yet cause the second method to be interpreted as a function inside the first method instead of another method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run your code on my machine and there the Run method gets called.

My best guess is what Paulo Scardine wrote, but since i can't reproduce the problem i can't actually debug it.